# Spark Transactional remove rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am working with dataframes with Scala in a banking process and I need remove some rows if the transaction is cancellation. For example if I have a cancellation, I must remove the previous row. In the case I have three cancellation continuous I must remove 3 previous rows.

DataFrame initial:

[image]

DataFrame expected

[image]

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combination of *inbuilt functions*, `udf` function and `window` function should help you get your desired result (*commented for clarity*)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Account").orderBy("Sequence").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def filterUdf = udf((array:Seq[Long], sequence: Long)=> !array.contains(sequence))

df.withColumn("collection", sum(when(col("Type") === "Cancellation", 1).otherwise(0)).over(windowSpec))   //getting the count of cancellation in each group
    .withColumn("Sequence", when(col("Type") === "Cancellation", col("Sequence")-col("collection")).otherwise(col("Sequence")))   //getting the difference between count and sequence number to get the sequence number of previous
    .withColumn("collection", collect_set(when(col("Type") === "Cancellation", col("Sequence")).otherwise(0)).over(windowSpec))   //collecting the differenced sequence number of cancellation 
    .filter(filterUdf(col("collection"), col("Sequence")))            //filtering out the rows calling the udf 
    .drop("collection")
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-------+-----------+--------+
|Account|Type       |Sequence|
+-------+-----------+--------+
|11047  |Aggregation|11      |
|1030583|Aggregation|1       |
|1030583|Aggregation|4       |
+-------+-----------+--------+
```

**Note: This solution works only when you have sequencial cancellation in each group of `Account`**

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot @Ramesh Maharjan, it works fine. I have learnt a lot with your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think a Map of stack data structure is useful in this case, with the key is account id. You push the Agg rows into stack until encountering a Cancel, then you pop the stack.

Comment: You can please give me a guide in code. I didn't get it.